# Ruby Gtk3 gem, SourceFile

Tags: ruby, file, rubygems, gtk3

The `gtksourceview3` gem appears to lack the `GtkSourceFile` api. I can't see it listed in the module's constants or classes. I think this is a fairly new API, so I understand if it is unimplemented at the moment. I'm wondering if there's anywhere to find an implementation status. Is the api there and I just can't see it?

Here's [my project, the startings of a code editor](https://github.com/Racinettee/coral).

Comment: I notice your project is missing a gemfile. Are you using bundler to manage dependencies? this is highly recommended for ruby projects. Could also give us some insight to your $LOAD_PATH and whether or not the gem was found http://bundler.io/gemfile.html

Comment: Thank you for informing me about bundler. I am quite new to ruby, but I'm loving it. This is the load path: ["/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1", "/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux", "/usr/local/lib/site_ruby", "/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1", "/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux", "/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby", "/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1", "/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux"]

Comment: Awesome! What do you get when you type 'gem env'

Comment: - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.23
- RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2013-11-22 patchlevel 484) [x86_64-linux]
- INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /var/lib/gems/1.9.1
- RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1
- EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/bin
- RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
  - ruby
  - x86_64-linux
- GEM PATHS:
 - /var/lib/gems/1.9.1
 - /home/user/.gem/ruby/1.9.1
 - /usr/share/rubygems-integration/1.9.1
 - /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all
- GEM CONFIGURATION:
 - :update_sources => true
 - :verbose => true
 - :benchmark => false
 - :backtrace => false
 - :bulk_threshold => 1000
- REMOTE SOURCES:
 - http://rubygems.org/

Comment: hey looking at this now, having trouble building native gem extensions on my mac but ill try and figure it out.

Comment: Cool, thanks. The native extensions are troublesome to build on windows too. The problem I found was pkgconfig not being correctly figured in that situation though.

Comment: Got it running, very cool. wish i could help more but this was best I could find - Heres the github page - https://github.com/ruby-gnome2/ruby-gnome2/tree/2.2.0/gtksourceview3 - looking at the codebase, it appears its a wrapper around a bunch of c code. Not sure how much is exposed through the gem itself and I am not familiar with c, sorry I cant be of more help :(